# Multiple user with multiple php versions ubuntu

Tags: server, ssh, php

I'm running Multiple PHP environments in a single server like PHP-5.6 PHP-7.0 PHP-7.1 PHP-7.2 PHP-7.3

and running sites almost every version of PHP like Magento and Moodle core PHP.

so here is my question when I access ssh (terminal)

it shows default PHP version 7.3 and I have to change PHP version every time  at the server
cause the standard user got same default PHP version no matter at what PHP version site running for a particular user

so is there any way where standard user change PHP version as they want without changing server default php version (like the same way we do in plesk and cpanel )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the `.profile` file that exist in each account's home folder. Add this to the bottom of the file:

```
alias php='/usr/bin/php7.4'
```

Be sure to replace `php7.4` with the appropriate version for that account. Once done, you can reload the profile:

```
. ~/.profile
```

***Note:** The space between the* `.` *and the* `~` *is important.*

Keep in mind that this will set the default php-cli version *just* for that account and not the main Apache user.